# 64 registers using MIPS architecture with 15 bits length

Tags: assembly, 32bit-64bit, cpu-architecture, opcode

I am having an assignment to make and it asks the following things : 
We have 64 registers where all of their commands they have 15bits length.
It also states that we got the following after we compile them(turn them into machine language). 7 commands with reference of 2 registers and 60 commands with reference of 1 register. It asks how many commands without register reference can we have..

This is what i though of but it appears i am having something wrong.

```
Since this is mips architecture each of the commands we use (add,all etc) will be using 32bits where for the r instructor we have:
opcode(6bits),rs(6bits),rt(6bits),rd(6bit),shamt(5bit),func(3bit)
because it says that we have 64 registers so we need 6 bits for each and the func is 3 due to the fact that we have max 7 functions.So in the case for example of all we have the following 
000000->opcode
000000->rs
6bit-> rt
6bit-> rd
5bit-> shame
3bit-> the function.
```

Is this correct or am i missing something? perhaps we are not supposed to use the r instructor but the i?What happens for the second operation when we have 60 commands and 1 register reference? what instructor can actually take only one register as an argument? Some help would be really appreciated and thanks

Comment: _"We have 64 registers where all of their commands they have 15bits length."_ Huh? _What_ has 15-bit length?

Comment: Some examples of MIPS instructions that only have one register operand: `jr`, `bltz`, `lui`.

Comment: thats what i am looking myself.perhaps the register can take up to 15 bits only? thats where i am stuck. The assignment says exactly those : Lets say we have a cpu where it has 64 registers whose command length is 15 bits. Perhaps its saying that hey i can only store 15 bits per register? but thats kinda unclear...

Comment: @Michael May i ask you since i am a noobie if the 0 register ar the j instructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is talking about mips, it's talking about a fictious architecture that you are about to design :)

7 commands with 2 registers needs 3+6+6=15 bits so uses all the bits available. It does leave 1 opcode free to encode the other instructions luckily :) Let's say `000b` is used for those.

This means, for the rest of the instructions we only have 12 bits remaining (since the first 3 are `000`). To encode 60 instructions we need 6 bits, and another 6 for the register, so that again uses up all the space.

However, we still have 4 opcodes free, we can use all of them for instructions without operands, and of course in we still have the 6 bits previously used for the registers, so we can encode 4*64=256 instructions that take no operands.

```
000 000000 xxxxxx = no operand block #1 with 64 instructions
000 000001 xxxxxx = no operand block #2 with 64 instructions
000 000010 xxxxxx = no operand block #3 with 64 instructions
000 000011 xxxxxx = no operand block #4 with 64 instructions
000 000100 rrrrrr = first instruction with 1 operand
000 111111 rrrrrr = last instructon with 1 operand (60 total)
001 ssssss tttttt = first instruction with 2 operands
111 ssssss tttttt = last instruction with 2 operands (7 total)
```

Comment: that was the first thought i had but then i though that hey we won't have an opcode if for the first example we have 15 bits so 6 +6 for the registers and 3 for the func.So you say we just avoid the func from the r instructor?

Comment: also may i ask you why you did write 000b? what is b supposed to be? sorry for asking you noobish questions i am just trying to get a better understanding of computer architecture. My mistake at first was that for the 7 commands i was thinking that instead of those 3 bits that were left to be the opcode i thought they were the func(r instructor) leaving the opcode empty and i was like hey you can have the opcode empty...

Comment: alright i got everything figured out.If you could lastly explain the 000b i would greatly appreciate!

Comment: `b` is just the suffix to indicate binary when not clear :)

Comment: i see. Thanks so much. I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Hello again and sorry to bother you mate. May i ask you what will happen in the case of instead of having 60 instructions with 1 register we have 10 instructions with 0 ? will the opcode for the last case be from 000 000000 000000 till 000 000000 0001001? so we have 63 instructions for the case with 1 register? thanks

Comment: Yeah, sounds sensible. That also leaves 54 combinations unused, though.

Comment: yes indeed. Perhaps you got a better solution? can those 54 combinations used for the other case with the 1 register? i guess no